# Why does 任 mean "no matter"? Where did the “no matter" sense of 任 come from?

Tags: glyph-origin

As a glyph, 任 [甲金文從「人」、「壬」聲，甲金文「壬」字作「工」形，金文於豎畫中間增一圓點，後圓點伸展為一橫。](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BB%BB)

As per [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%BB#Glyph_origin), 任 originated from

> semantic *[亻](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA#Chinese)* (“person”) + phonetic *[壬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A3%AC#Chinese)* (OC *l̥ʰeːŋʔ, *njɯm) – **to carry on a shoulder pole**.
>
> Note that its phonetic part [壬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A3%AC#Chinese) (*OC *njɯm*) may be the graphical representation of 任, depicting a shoulder pole rotated by 90 degrees.

As per [ZDIC](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%BB%BB), how did 任 mean

> (1) 表示让步关系，相当于“纵使”、“即使 ” [even if]
>
> (2) 表示条件关系，相当于“不论”、“无论” [no matter(what，who，how，etc.)] 。如:任事儿(所有的事);任吗儿(不论什么);任么(无论什么)

? How does this sense  relate to 任's original sense "**to carry on a shoulder pole**"?

Is this sense of ["無論"](https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=9239&q=1&word=%E4%BB%BB#order2) related to [任's other senses](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BB%BB) below?

| 詞類 | 英文意義 |
| --- | --- |
| n. | duty, office, official position |
| v. | trust to, rely on, confide in; appoint, employ; bear, be responsible for, assume office, take up a job; allow, tolerate, let |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person carrying a pole is **appointed** a position, that's why 任 carries the meaning of "appoint"

When a person has been appointed a position, he is also **granted** certain power and it was how 任 obtained the meaning of "granted" which extended to mean "no matter"

granted = admit as a fact

Example:

**granted** you are strong, **but** you can't beat me = **doesn't matter** that you are strong, you can't beat me

**granted** (a fact) --> but it doesn't mater =  **doesn't matter** what is granted (this fact)

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand ""granted" which extended to mean "no matter"". Please elaborate? Please write more details?

Comment: [granted (a fact)   + but...]  = [no matter (a fact) + but....]

Comment: granted --> but it does mater  --> doesn't matter

Comment: Sorry, but I still confused. Particularly "but it does mater --> doesn't matter"??? How can something matter, but then this same thing does not matter???

Comment: @Monica [granted]  is always followed by [but]; "granted X is true but Y still happens" = "Y still happens,  doesn't matter X is true" see my example sentence

Comment: "Granted" and "given" are used the same way in English, and in many other European languages. Compare English "Well that's a _given_".